# First assembly program error "too many references for mov"

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation

In the following assembly code I am trying to implement a multiplication method using bitwise shifts etc but I am getting two errors over and over, "too many memory references for 'mov'" as well as "ambiguous operand size for 'cmp/and/mov/shl/shr'". Any ideas?

Thanks guys. The associated errors are below, as requested.

```
    .intel_syntax
    .data

    .globl x
x:  .long 0

    .globl y
y:  .long 0
    .text

    .globl multiply
multiply:
    push    ebp #These two statements are necessary
    mov ebp,esp

    mov eax,0
    mov ebx,x
    mov edx,y

LOOP:
    cmp ebx,0
    je  DONE

    mov ecx,ebx
    and ecx,1
    cmp ecx,1
    jne LOOPC   #jump to continued loop if low_bit(x) not 1

    add eax,edx

LOOPC:
    shr ebx,1
    shl edx,1
    jmp LOOP

DONE:
    pop ebp #Necessary statement
    ret     #return
```

Error messages:

```
multiply.s: Assembler messages:
multiply.s:0: Warning: end of file in comment; newline inserted
multiply.s:15: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
multiply.s:17: Error: ambiguous operand size for `mov'
multiply.s:18: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
multiply.s:19: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
multiply.s:22: Error: ambiguous operand size for `cmp'
multiply.s:25: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
multiply.s:26: Error: ambiguous operand size for `and'
multiply.s:27: Error: ambiguous operand size for `cmp'
multiply.s:30: Error: too many memory references for `add'
multiply.s:33: Error: ambiguous operand size for `shr'
multiply.s:34: Error: ambiguous operand size for `shl'
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicated the line(s) on which you are getting those errors.

Comment: Try `.intel_syntax noprefix` instead of just `.intel_syntax` (or adding `%` to all of your registers)

Comment: Added the errors as requested.

Comment: @flapjackery: So, where's the code you're talking about?

Answer (score 8):

You are missing `%` in front of all your register names:

So it should be:

```
mov %eax,0
mov %ebx,x
mov %edx,y
```

As it is, it is parsing them as variables to memory locations. (without the `%`, they'd be the same as `x` and `y` which **are** memory references.)

EDIT:

Ah... Looks like ughoavgfhw already pointed this out in the comments.